# What brand is this brick with a logo that looks like an elongated C and a square?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, clone-brands

Can anyone tell me about this brick? There is no Lego logo on it. It looks well made and fits perfectly with real Lego bricks.

[image: logo that looks like an elongated C and a square]

Comment: I have an 8x8 plate I just got in a mix of Lego and knockoffs, without boxes or instructions. There's no markings anywhere else, except **4006B** on the bottom. A lot of Google Image searching has not yielded any joy.

Comment: Looks like the [Betty Crocker](https://www.google.com/search?q=betty+crocker+logo) logo to me.

Comment: No idea but I think the logo looks like a person wearing a helmet, looking to the left